# How to include a large number of images in the appendix?

Tags: floats, subfloats, appendices

I would like to put 17 images in the appendix. The 17 images belong together but they span multiple pages. I would like to put 6 images on one page (2 pages per row, 3 rows). So in the end I will have 3 pages. I will do it in the following way:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \subfloat[Caption 1]{%
    \input{figure1.tikz}
  }
  \hfill
  \subfloat[Caption 2]{%
    \input{figure2.tikz}
  }

  \smallskip

  \subfloat[Caption 3]{%
    \input{figure3.tikz}
  }
  \hfill
  \subfloat[Caption 4]{%
    \input{figure4.tikz}
  }

  \caption{My overall caption}
\end{figure}
```

I have found some solutions for the page break with subfloats. But the problem is when I use an outer figure environment the overall caption of that figure would be at the last page (third page) which is bad. Moreover, the figures would be names (a)-(q) which is also not so nice for such a large number of images. Another option would be to include each figure in its own figure environment (that means no overall caption).

Which method is prefered for including such a large number of images in the appendix? As said the figures conceptually belongs together.

Comment: Why don't you use a `longtable` environment (or a breakable `tabularx`)? You could use `\captionof{figure}{your caption}` and repeat it at the bottom of each page.

Comment: This is really off-topic for this site. We do the how? You are asking the what? Or whether? That said, what's bad about labelling the images (1)-(17) or whatever?